# What's the differences between this Infinispan cache factories for Hibernate second level cache?

Tags: caching, cluster-computing, wildfly-10, infinispan

I'm trying to figure out the difference between this factories, used in `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` property.

Example:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory" />
<property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager" value="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate" />
```

There are 4 possible options.

The 2 options that I know something about is:

1. `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory`: for standalone aplications (not in a cluster, I think).
2. `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory`: this is bounded to a JNDI in the property `hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager`.

And I don't have any idea about these 2:

3. `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.SharedInfinispanRegionFactory`: ?
4. `org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory`: ?

We have a cluster configured on Wildfly 10.1.0 using domain mode. We want to share the entity cache among the nodes and we are having some doubts about how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Wildfly, you don't have to worry about setting the region factory class because Wildfly uses Infinispan as second-level cache provider by default. It's all explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingtheInfinispansecondlevelcache).

All you have to do is enable `hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache` and you're good to go. See examples in the docu.

Comment: Thanks! But this default configuration makes the cache distributed among the nodes of the cluster?

Comment: The default configuration, standalone.xml, is designed for single node, but there are multiple configurations shipped with Wildfly, including clustered.xml and others, which are designed for a cluster env.

Comment: Btw, regardless of the Wildfly configuration (standalone or clustered), your persistence.xml remains the same, nothing you need to touch there other than what I suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Galder, +1!

Regarding the purpose of [org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.SharedInfinispanRegionFactory][1] + [org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory][2], these classes extend the Hibernate ORM [hibernate-infinispan][3] implementation classes, the purpose being to start the internal WildFly Infinispan cache services used for the JPA second level caching.  They also deal with configuration as well.  The below links may become outdated over time, as I think we [3] code might move to the Infinispan project (eventually).

A little more of the related code is at [HibernateSecondLevelCache.java][4], which backs up what Galder said.  You can see that the WildFly JPA container automatically is setting the region factory class for you (if caching is enabled via [HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java][5].

I'm not sure if the code links are helpful to you, I thought they might be. :)

As a stackoverflow newbie, I am not allowed to post with more than 2 links, which is why [3] - [5] are invalid links.

Scott

[1] https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jpa/hibernate5/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate5/infinispan/SharedInfinispanRegionFactory.java

[2] https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jpa/hibernate5/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate5/infinispan/InfinispanRegionFactory.java

[3] github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-infinispan

[4] github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jpa/hibernate5/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate5/HibernateSecondLevelCache.java

[5] github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/jpa/hibernate5/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate5/HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java#L91

Answer (score 1):

The configuration envolves **Infinispan, Hibernate and JGroups.**

Using domain-mode on Wildfly10 you'll need this configuration on your application EAR:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
```

Your server group need to use a profile that has the ha resources(high availability) such as **full-ha** or **ha** profiles. These profiles have the Infinispan and JGroups default configuration.

Then, you need to have the **private** 'Network Interfaces' on **ALL** Hosts' configuration that share the cache. JGroups uses the private  Edit the domain/configuration/host.xml or use the wildfly console admin to add this configuration (**200.0.0.171** needs to be replaced by the server's IP):

```
 <interfaces>
    ...
    <interface name="private">

        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.private:200.0.0.171}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- .... -->
</interfaces>
```

For example, supposing you have a HostController HC1(with server-1 and server-2) and HC2(with server-3 and server-4)
Starting all the servers and Host Controllers,  you'll see on your server.log:

```
INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel hibernate
....
....
Received new cluster view for channel hibernate:  [HC1:server-1, HC2-server-2, HC2-server-3, HC2-server-4]
```

Comment: You don't need any to specify any region factory class, nor `hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager` property when running inside Wildfly. It might work but it's unnecessary and confuses users. If there's any issues with my proposed solution, please do let me know.